# HTTP to HTTPS redirect causes critical chained request in Google Page Speed Insights

Tags: redirects, wordpress, https, google-pagespeed

My WordPress website is configured to use HTTPS. After running the site through Google Page Speed Insights, the report shows a section labeled `Avoid chaining critical requests 1 chain found`

Expanding it shows a tree view like this:

```
  Initial Navigation
    |-http://example.com
        |-https://example.com
            |-…fonts/eicons.woff2
```

What puzzles me is that it starts to communicate through `http://` before using `https://`

Is this the expected behavior? Or would it be possible to get rid of the initial `http://` communication attempt, to increase the sites response time?

Comment: What request is this for? If the initial request is over HTTP then you can't get rid of the initial `http://`.